# A word for "nobody depends on me"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, vocabulary

If I do not depend on anybody, I can say:

> I am independent

And if nobody depends on me. Is there a *monoword* to describe that?

Comment: *Lonely*, I suppose.

Comment: Useless, maybe ;)

Comment: I suggest _Unreliable_.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who has no dependents and therefore no responsibilities can be described as *unencumbered*. Here are two definitions of the word from online dictionaries:

> not burdened with cares or responsibilities
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unencumbered
>
> A person is unencumbered when they're traveling light — they're not
>   struggling to carry 5 suitcases. But if you have no worries or
>   responsibilities, you're also unencumbered — nothing is weighing on
>   your mind. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/unencumbered

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary? I guess....
It's a pretty lonely existance I think though... being needed by no one.